# Problem with EF Core migration on Azure Function v2 on .NET Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, .net-core, azure-functions

I have a project called `MyApp` which contains [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) Models. To **create the initial database** from those models I used the following command in the **Package Manager Console of Visual Studio**:

```sh
dotnet ef migrations -v add InitialCreate
```

The directory structure of my Project is something like this:

```
MyApp
|-bin
|   |-Debug
|   |   |-netcoreapp2.1
|   |   |  |-bin
.   .   .  |  |-...
.   .   .  |  |-MyApp.dll
.   .   .  |  |-...
           |-MyApp.deps.json
           |-MyApp.runtimeconfig.dev.json
           |-MyApp.runtimeconfig.json
```

#### The Problem

As I run the above command to create the initial database, the following error pops up:

```
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest
(MyApp.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'MyApp', version: '1.0.0'
    path: 'MyApp.dll'
```

So, the **command could not locate the `MyApp.dll` file which was in the `bin` directory**.

This is clear from the following verbose output:

```
PM> dotnet ef migrations -v add InitialCreate
Using project 'C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject\MyApp.csproj'.
Using startup project 'C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject\MyApp.csproj'.
Writing 'C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject\obj\MyApp.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\rohan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4BF.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject\MyApp.csproj
Writing 'C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject\obj\MyApp.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\rohan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEB2.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject\MyApp.csproj
dotnet build C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject\MyApp.csproj /verbosity:quiet /nologo

Build succeeded.

    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:17.49
dotnet exec --depsfile C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\MyApp.deps.json 
--additionalprobingpath C:\Users\rohan\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" 
--runtimeconfig C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\MyApp.runtimeconfig.json 
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.700\DotnetTools\dotnet-ef\2.1.11\tools\netcoreapp2.1\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll" 
migrations add InitialCreate 
--assembly C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\MyApp.dll 
--startup-assembly C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\MyApp.dll 
--project-dir C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject\ --language C# 
--working-dir C:\Users\rohan\Projects\MySolution\myproject --verbose --root-namespace MyApp
dotnet : Error:
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet ef migrations -v add InitialCreate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyApp.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'MyApp', version: '1.0.0'
    path: 'MyApp.dll'
```

Basically, **the `dll` file path in `--assembly` and `--startup-assembly` options are incorrect**. This is because the **generated (by the above command) `MyApp.deps.json`** contains the following:

```
{
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1",
    "signature": "..."
  },
  "compilationOptions": {},
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1": {
      "MyApp/1.0.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          ...
        },
        "runtime": {
          "MyApp.dll": {}
        }
      },
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Here, inside the `runtime` JSON object in the `MyApp/1.0.0` contains the **relative path to the `dll` file as `MyApp.dll`** whereas it **should have been `bin/MyApp.dll`**.

What should I do so that correct path is written in the `runtime` JSON object?

Comment: you're jamming that much logic into 1 azure function?

Comment: No. Why do you think so? My azure functions are really small.

Comment: Because you need an entire orm to manage your database calls

Comment: Ohh, I could've used SqlClient but I thought ORM would make the job easier.

Comment: Yeah, you're not cool unless you're manually writing sql and using ADO.NET.  Why use a tool that uses reflection to do it for you.  Also, use notepad.  jfc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a very similar issue. After hours of searching and experimenting, I found this post: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14679

Separating the database stuff into a separate Class Library project and then adding the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory fixed it for me.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

After much research myself, I found this work around from here:

https://dev.to/azure/using-entity-framework-with-azure-functions-50aa

But needed to adapt it for a n-tier setup whereby the models were in another project (along with other projects). I needed to copy all dlls starting with 'Crank' (feature code name) not just the dll of the start up project.

**The end fix was to add the following the following to the startup csproj**

```
 <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
<Exec Command="copy /Y &quot;$(TargetDir)bin\Crank*.dll&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)Crank*.dll&quot;" /></Target>
```

This I understand will copy the project dlls so that the EF add-migration and update-database can use them.

Note the step needed to set the environment variable also before running add-migration or update-database:

$env:CrankDealershipDatabase="Server=.\ss2016,1433;Database=CrankDealership_Develop;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

These were the packages at the time:

Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions 1.0.0

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.6

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.29

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.6

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.2.6

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.2.6

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.2.3